# how to POST Avro bytes to flask endpoint

Tags: python, flask, unicode, avro, flask-restful

problem: when a POST request is sent to a flask endpoint where a field consists of raw bytes (Apache Avro format), flask automatically attempts to decode the bytes into unicode which messes up the data.

for example, when a POST request is sent via python test client as follows:

```
# part of a python unittest
data = {
    'flavor': 'sweet',
}

schema = {
    'name': 'SimpleData',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [{'name': 'flavor', 'type': 'string'}]
}

schema = json.dumps(schema)
avro_bytes = to_avro_files(data, schema) 
simple_data = {
    'avro_bytes': avro_bytes,
    'weather': 'warm'
}

# NOTE the avro_bytes here is of type str, and content as follows
(Pdb) avro_bytes
'Obj\x01\x04\x16avro.schema\xb4\x01{"fields": [{"type": "string", "name": "flavor"}], "type": "record", "name": "SimpleData"}\x14avro.codec\x08null\x00\x80\xb0\xef\xc1\xea\xdc\xbc\xb4!\x9c\xb0\xcd\x8eS\xafu\x02\x0c\nsweet\x80\xb0\xef\xc1\xea\xdc\xbc\xb4!\x9c\xb0\xcd\x8eS\xafu'

headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form'
response = self.client.post('/my_api_endpoint', data=simple_data, headers=headers)
```

by the time the request is received by the flask app, looking into the request body we have the following:

```
(Pdb) request.form['weather']
u'warm'
(Pdb) request.form['avro_bytes']
u'Obj\x01\x04\x16avro.schema\ufffd\x01{"fields": [{"type": "string", "name": "flavor"}], "type": "record", "name": "SimpleData"}\x14avro.codec\x08null\x00\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u073c\ufffd!\ufffd\ufffd\u034eS\ufffdu\x02\x0c\nsweet\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u073c\ufffd!\ufffd\ufffd\u034eS\ufffdu'
```

where both args are converted to unicode, which is fine for 'weather', but 'avro_bytes' got invalide unicode characters such as `u'\ufffd'` which makes it impossible to encode it back to the original avro_bytes.

In short, how to prevent flask app from trying to decode the avro_bytes into unicode?

thanks!

Comment: The characater `\uFFFD` is not invalid, it's the replacement character �. I'm not sure if it helps a lot, but this is a sign that flask was trying to be clever here in the decoding process.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?